# time.sleep() will freeze on Virtual machine

Tags: python

I have an automation code that will take a time from a certain website and uses this as an argument for time.sleep(). Usually time is more than 1hr. I included in this code some function that prevents sleep/lock/hibernation of the pc. The code runs fine on my laptop and it also runs fine on a Windows VM.

My problem is when I disconnect from the VM's interface, when connect again after a while, I fiind the code sleeping even though time used as an argument for time.sleep() is way over passed Tried another approach with a countdown, but the same problem ( seems like countdown freezes while I am disconnected from VM)

Comment: Nobody can possibly help you unless you share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you include information about how you run the code on the VM.

Comment: because the VM goes to sleep as well , maybe ??

Comment: @doneforaiur  I tried to run it from executable (this is the way it should run)  but also from pycharm

Comment: @pippo1980 ON STRIKE  i have a function that will press volume up and down every 2 minutes to prevent sleep on VM . This works on my pc at least

Comment: you should put it in your question so to exclude the possibility